# could not connect PostgreSQL server

Tags: postgresql

When I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL, I gain this message :

```
Unable to connect to server:
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

And When I Installed PostgreSQL, I gain the ERROR :

```
Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly. The database cluster initialisation failed.
```

My assumption is that I have some problems with `data` folder in PostgreSQL because `data` folder is empty.

Comment: You need to [initialize](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html) the postgresql cluster. There might be a script to run on your distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that you have just installed the postgres software and not configured it.

Please follow the below link to configure it as well.

[setting up and configuring postgres on windows](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/idol/IDOL_12_0/MediaServer/Guides/html/English/Content/Getting_Started/Configure/_TRN_Set_up_PostgreSQL.htm)